# How do I access uploaded group files for a group on Facebook?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to read group posts and files posted in my group through python. I can see group feeds in graph API but when i try to see the files uploaded in the group I get empty array 
(
         {
           "data": []
         }
)

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting. Please include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of your post.

Comment: As Richard Erickson mentioned, you need to throw us a bone here and provide some more info by following the MVCE guidelines.

Comment: We filed a bug report to Facebook regarding this issue. They have confirmed that this is a bug and now they are correcting this bug.
Thanks to All

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a user access token for a member of the group with user_managed_groups permissions, the group is public and its privacy setting is set to `OPEN`, you should be able to get the files uploaded in the group with:

A `GET` request using `/{group-id}/files`, something like this:

```
/v2.3/{group-id}/files HTTP/1.1 Host: graph.facebook.com
```

Comment: I am still not able to get files using /{group-id}/files, but i am getting the feeds.


{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#602) author_id is not a member of the group_file table.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 602
  }
}

Comment: @kavishbhatia Can you actually post the entire code you're using? Also, what version of the API are you using? If you're using FQL tables, please note that after API version 2.0, FQL tables were deprecated. Instead, you need to use the Facebook [Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event).

Comment: @Malvin9000 - I get this error with the FB API Explorer!  Using: /v2.3/{group-id}/files  for a group which I am an admin! Does it work in the FB API Explorer for you?